# Read custom headers from HTTP response in Elm

Tags: cors, elm

I am using [`Http.expectStringResponse`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/latest/Http#expectStringResponse) to pass the HTTP response metadata along with the body (or error). And I log the `Dict.keys metadata.headers` into the console. According to log, Elm does not pass all the headers. As seen from the attached image, the set of headers in the dev-tools network tab is a superset of the headers in the log. I cannot find explanation to this in the docs. Hopefully Elm community can shed some light.

[image]

## Update

As pointed out by glennsl and Gareth Latty, this is CORS related and has nothing to do with Elm. `XMLHttpRequest` produces same result.

Comment: [Probably CORS-related](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers)

Comment: Rather than an edit, if this solves your problem, feel free to accept my answer—or better yet, post your own answer detailing the CORS issue and how you fixed it and accept that!

Comment: Gareth, I voted up, but not sure how to actually accept the answer.

Comment: @yagger You should see [a tick mark you can press to turn green and accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I can't reproduce this.](https://ellie-app.com/7rykHNxHgwja1) There *are* some headers that won't be returned—specifically `Set-Cookie` and `Set-Cookie2`, but all the ones in your example should be, at least as far as Elm is concerned.

You can see the implementation for [`Http`'s header parsing](https://github.com/elm/http/blob/2.0.0/src/Elm/Kernel/Http.js#L87):

```
_Http_parseHeaders(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders())

...

function _Http_parseHeaders(rawHeaders)
{
    if (!rawHeaders)
    {
        return __Dict_empty;
    }

    var headers = __Dict_empty;
    var headerPairs = rawHeaders.split('\r\n');
    for (var i = headerPairs.length; i--; )
    {
        var headerPair = headerPairs[i];
        var index = headerPair.indexOf(': ');
        if (index > 0)
        {
            var key = headerPair.substring(0, index);
            var value = headerPair.substring(index + 2);

            headers = A3(__Dict_update, key, function(oldValue) {
                return __Maybe_Just(__Maybe_isJust(oldValue)
                    ? value + ', ' + oldValue.a
                    : value
                );
            }, headers);
        }
    }
    return headers;
}
```

You can see in Elm, no filtering is happening.

[`getAllResponseHeaders()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getAllResponseHeaders) does filter the two previously mentioned headers:

> A `ByteString` representing all of the response's headers (except those whose field name is `Set-Cookie` or `Set-Cookie2`) separated by CRLF, or `null` if no response has been received. If a network error happened, an empty string is returned.

As you are seeing this, it is likely something specific to the situation causing the browser not to return all the headers. We would need more information (ideally an example where we can reproduce the issue) to say more. As suggested [in glennsl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234034/read-custom-headers-from-http-response-in-elm/59248858#comment104680569_59234034), it seems likely this might be [a CORS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945587/xmlhttprequest-getallresponseheaders-not-returning-all-the-headers). I would suggest trying using `getAllResponsHeaders()` directly in that environment and removing Elm from the equation.